# Regex to match SSN in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need a regex to match SSN. The condition are as follows:

1. Need to be of 9 digits.
2. Of the form xxxxxxxxx or xxx-xx-xxxx
3. First three and last four numbers cannot be all zero. For example 000-xx-xxxx, xxx-xx-0000, 000-xx-0000 is invalid.

I have come up with this:

```
((0(?!00)|[1-9])\d{4}(0(?!000)|[1-9])\d{3})|((0(?!00)|[1-9])\d{2}-\d{2}-(0(?!000)|[1-9])\d{3})
```

It does the work but i am looking for a neater way to do this.
Secondly what is the best practice in regards to subgroup. What are better in terms of capturing and non capturing sub group.

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel. do reasearch. why are those: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=ssn&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 not good enough?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I would use 4 or 5 separate comparisons, not a single regex. What's the point of cramming everything into one regex?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for suggesting. Went through it and came up with this:  `((?!000)\d{5}(?!0000)\d{4})|((?!000)\d{3}-\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4})`. Looks much neater although is there a better way to handle or.

Comment: @melpomene I need to come up with a single neat regex.

Comment: @ctwheels New at it.. thanks for the suggestion. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: @melpomene yes..my bad !

Comment: That said, in Perl I'd use `m{\A (?! 000 ) \d\d\d -? \d\d -? (?! 0000 ) \d\d\d\d \z}xa`. Translation to Python is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a cleaner RegEx solution to matching different formats for a SSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033537/looking-for-a-cleaner-regex-solution-to-matching-different-formats-for-a-ssn)

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: [`^(?!000|.+0{4})(?:\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/JHB6W0/6)

If you have a text and you want to match SSN use:

`\b(?!000|.+0{4})(?:\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})\b`.

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `|` Or

**Python code**:

```
import re

array = ['000123333','001245565','012548785','123456854','213254000','213250000','123544155','125875400','154878880','000-23-1234','001-23-0000','001-23-1000','120-00-1200','005-64-5541','121-25-1258']

for item in array:
    print(bool(re.match(r'^(?!000|.+0{4})(?:\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$', item)))
```

Output:

```
000123333 => False
001245565 => True
012548785 => True
123456854 => True
213254000 => True
213250000 => False
123544155 => True
125875400 => True
154878880 => True
000-23-1234 => False
001-23-0000 => False
001-23-1000 => True
120-00-1200 => True
005-64-5541 => True
121-25-1258 => True
```